# Select exact match using str_detect

Tags: r, regex

I have the following code

```
titanic <- titanic %>% mutate(title = ifelse(str_detect(name,"Mr.|Ms.|Mme."), "Hombre casado",
                                    ifelse(str_detect(name, "Master."), "Hombre soltero",
                                    ifelse(str_detect(name, "Miss."), "Mujer soltera",

                                    ifelse(str_detect(name, "Mrs.|Mlle."), "Mujer casada",  "Otro")))))
```

I have the following dataframe:

```
name <- c("Mr Sergio", "Mrs Maria")
surname <- c("Nnunci", "Gonzalez")

df <- data.frame(name, surname)
```

The idea of this function is to add to the title column their marital status depending if in name column there is Mr Ms or Mrs.

For example, if in the column "name" I have Mr|Ms|Mme (one of them), then in title I have to put "Hombre casado" which mean "Married man".

It's working well except for "Mrs." which mean "Married women", because when I apply this function to my dataset, Married women appear as "Hombre casado" (Married man). I think it's about the pattern I am using for detecting the types.

Output:

```
    name      surname        title
    Mr Sergio  Nnunci     Hombre Casado
    Mrs Maria  Gonzalez   Mujer Casada
```

Some idea?

Comment: You should wrap the patterns in `fixed()`, like `str_detect(name, fixed("Mr.|Ms.|Mme."))`. If you don't do that the patterns is evaluated as a regular expression in which a `.` means *"every character"*

Comment: the period is a wild card character in regards to regular expression.  Try escaping the `.` with `\\.`

Comment: Two ideas: 1. you could structure your code so that the "Mrs" checks come *before* the "Mr" checks. 2. (better) you could use the regex special `\b` that matches *word boundaries* (white space, punctuation, line ends), making your patterns more like `"Mr\\b|Ms\\b|Mme\\b"`. Also heed Dave's advice - in regex a `.` will match any one character. If you want to literally match a `.` you need to escape it. However, in this case I think you are better off using word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks all of u finally I used what u said about word boundaries!!! Thanks all!!!

Comment: As I side comment, I don't know which version of titanic data you are using, but I would assume `Ms.` is equivalent to Miss, `Mlle` for Mademoiselle, also equivalent to Miss, and `Mme` to be Madame, equivalent to Mrs.

Comment: Yes you are right!